# Unable to have proper ID in MS Access using Java GUI

Tags: java, swing

I have 2 questions where i couldn't find any answers online.
I've tried several things to do but it's not really working

1. I attached the code down, but... Everytime i press "ADAUGA"(means Insert) button in my database it will give me a bigger number in ID. (Photo attached) For example if i add now another words, it will give me ID 28(probably)
2. How can i "delete" the error: "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" " whenever i press "Adauga" it will give me this error (Photo attached)

Code:

```
package fereastra1;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
class Fereastra1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JLabel l1,l2,l3,l4,l5;
JTextField t1,t2,t3,t4,t5;
JButton b1,b2,b3;
public Fereastra1()
{
    ResultSet rs;
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    l1=new JLabel("titlu_film");  
    l2=new JLabel("an_film");       
    l3=new JLabel("timp_film");        
    l4=new JLabel("film_limba");
    l5=new JLabel("ID");


    t1=new JTextField(20);  
    t2=new JTextField(10);
    t3=new JTextField(10);
    t4=new JTextField(10);
    t5=new JTextField(10);


    b1=new JButton("ADAUGA");
    b2=new JButton("STERGE");
    b3=new JButton("MODIFICA");

    add(l1);add(t1);add(l2);add(t2);
    add(l3);add(t3);add(l4);add(t4);add(l5);add(t5);add(b1);add(b2);add(b3);
    setSize(1000,400);   
    setTitle("Conectivitate");
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    try{
    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:\\Temp\\film.accdb");
PreparedStatement psmt=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO filme (titlu_film,an_film,timp_film,film_limba) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
PreparedStatement psmts=con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM filme WHERE film_id=?");
PreparedStatement psmtss=con.prepareStatement("Update filme SET titlu_film=?,an_film=?,timp_film=?,film_limba=? WHERE film_id=?");
        String nume,data,timp,limba;
        int id;
        nume= t1.getText();
        data= t2.getText();
        timp=t3.getText();
        limba= t4.getText();
        id=Integer.parseInt(t5.getText());
        if(e.getSource()==b1)
    {   
        psmt.setString(1,nume);
        psmt.setString(2,data);
        psmt.setString(3,timp);
        psmt.setString(4,limba);
        psmt.executeUpdate();
    }
        if(e.getSource()==b2)
        {
        psmts.setInt(1,id);
        psmts.executeUpdate(); 
        }
        if(e.getSource()==b3)
        {
        psmtss.setString(1,nume);
        psmtss.setString(2,data);
        psmtss.setString(3,timp);
        psmtss.setString(4,limba);
        psmtss.setInt(5,id);
        psmtss.executeUpdate();
        }

        con.close();
    System.out.println("Success");
    }catch(Exception r){
    System.out.println(r);
            }
}


public static void main(String[] arr)
{
    new Fereastra1();
}
}
```

Photo Q1:
[image: Q1 photo]

Photo Q2:
[image: Q2 photo]

Comment: Don't use a single ActionListener. You should NOT have if/else statements in your ActionListener to determine which button was clicked. Keep the logic simple with one PreparedStatement and the code to set the parameters for that PreparedStatement. You will be less likely to make silly mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

Move the following line:

```
id=Integer.parseInt(t5.getText());
```

before the lines containing `setInt`, so it executes only for the buttons `b2` and `b3`, not for button `b1`.

Comment: That was a great idea, i don't know why i wasn't thinking about that. Small  mistakes or bigger i guess :-) Thanks a lot ! The problem is that even now, if i'm adding a new row, it will give me  ID 29

Comment: So, what is the problem now? You want the newly generated ID to be displayed in th TextField, but it remains empty?

Comment: As i stated in the Q1, the thing is that everytime i give an input to the textfields , it will not generate to my "filme" table the next ID, as you can see in the first photo(P1) , it's just giving me a "27" filme_id and not 14 or whatever is the next one.

Comment: That's the way AutoNumber fields work in Microsoft Access (and also in SQL Server): after a number is used for a row, that value is not used again, even if that row is deleted before any other row is added (or even if the transaction which tried to add that row is rolled back due to an error).

Comment: So i should get used to it i guess ,  as other an other choice i don't have i guess.